# Does C# YamlDotNet library support the merge key?

Tags: c#, yamldotnet

I have a problem with C# YamlDotNet library
http://www.aaubry.net/page/YamlDotNet

Do you know if the library does support the 'Merge Key' ?
http://yaml.org/type/merge.html

This does not seem to work for me.
In other libraries, like PyYaml the merge works fine.

Answer (score 2):

### Edit

YamlDotNet now has support for merge keys.

[Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SHiG9e):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using YamlDotNet.Serialization;
using YamlDotNet.Core;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var yaml = @"
anchor: &default
  key1: &myValue value1
  key2: value2
alias:
  <<: *default
  key2: Overriding key2
  key3: value3
";

        var reader = new EventReader(new MergingParser(new Parser(new StringReader(yaml))));

        var deserializer = new Deserializer();
        var result = deserializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>>(reader);

        var alias = result["alias"];
        Console.WriteLine("key1 = {0}", alias["key1"]);
        Console.WriteLine("key2 = {0}", alias["key2"]);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
key1 = value1
key2 = Overriding key2
```

---

<strike>Merge keys are not (yet) supported. It is a planned feature, but right now you will have to implement it yourself.</strike>

Comment: It works if you use it this way, but fails if you try to merge in the DOM from multiple source modes.  `children.Add` throws in the `YamlMappingNode` ctor with duplicate key.  What should we do here?  My actual use case is I want to control the anchor tokens that are generated and also to ensure that aliasing is maximal in the generated output.  Is YamlDotNet the right tool for this kind of normalization?