# yamldotnet merge 2 yaml files (deep merge function)

Tags: c#, merge, yaml, yamldotnet

is there a simple way in the library to deep merge 2 yaml files ?

I found this question : [Does C# YamlDotNet library support the merge key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18894610/does-c-sharp-yamldotnet-library-support-the-merge-key)

but it mean I need to convert my yaml file to yaml merge syntax ?